# Output tex file directly from stargazer?

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

Is there any possibility of having stargazer directly produce tex files from regression output, similar to the way outreg2 does this in Stata?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I completely missed the "out" option of stargazer, that does just what I wanted.